# Trying to write a python recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following list:

```
list = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']
```

What is the best way to write a recursive function that will pick one letter from each group of three and return all possible combinations/permutations:

E.g. output as follows:

> A, AD, ADG, ADH, ADI, AEG, AEH, AEI, AFG, AFH, AFI
>
> B, BD, BDG, BDH, BDI, BEG, BEH, BEI, BFG, BFH, BFI
>
> C, CD, CDG, CDH, CDI, CEG, CEH, CEI, CFG, CFH, CFI
>
> D, DG, DGA, DGB, DGC, DHA, ... and so on ...

I'm learning recursive functions. I have spend 7 straight hours on this problem so far and still nowhere near.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please add what you have tried.

Comment: You don't need recursion for this

Comment: Say you've given a function `foo()` that solve this problem for groups of size 2, how can you use it?

Answer (score 2):

Consider that for the empty list, your result is an empty list (this is your 'base case'), i.e.

```
f([]) == ""
```

For any non-empty list, you take each character of the first list element (the 'head' of the list) and prepend it to each string returned by recursively applying your function to the remainder (the 'tail') of the list (this is your 'recursive case'):

```
f(['ABC'])
  == 'A' + f([]), 'B' + f([]), 'C' + f([])
  == 'A' + '', 'B' + '', 'C' + ''
  == 'A', 'B', 'C'

f(['ABC', DEF'])
  == 'A' + f(['DEF']), 'B' + f(['DEF']), 'C' + f(['DEF'])
  == 'A' + 'D' + f([]), 'A' + 'E' + f([]), 'A' + 'F' + f([]), 'B' + 'D' + f([]) ...
  == 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'CD', 'CE', 'CF'
```

In Python, that could be expressed as (somewhat inefficient and verbose, but the point is to show the algorithm):

```
def f(xs):
    if not xs:
        yield ''
    else:
        head = xs[0]
        tail = xs[1:]

        for char in head:
            yield char
            for s in f(tail):
                yield char + s
```

Calling this function like

```
print list(f(['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']))
```

prints

```
['A', 'AD', 'ADG', 'ADG', 'ADH', 'ADH', 'ADI', 'ADI', 'AE', 'AEG', 'AEG', 'AEH', 'AEH', 'AEI', 'AEI', 'AF', 'AFG', 'AFG', 'AFH', 'AFH', 'AFI', 'AFI', 'B', 'BD', 'BDG', 'BDG', 'BDH', 'BDH', 'BDI', 'BDI', 'BE', 'BEG', 'BEG', 'BEH', 'BEH', 'BEI', 'BEI', 'BF', 'BFG', 'BFG', 'BFH', 'BFH', 'BFI', 'BFI', 'C', 'CD', 'CDG', 'CDG', 'CDH', 'CDH', 'CDI', 'CDI', 'CE', 'CEG', 'CEG', 'CEH', 'CEH', 'CEI', 'CEI', 'CF', 'CFG', 'CFG', 'CFH', 'CFH', 'CFI', 'CFI']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following program should be close to what you asked for. You may need to adjust the code for purposes of efficiency and ordering of the values it produces. Note that the recursive function is embedded within `possibilities` and ends up calling itself at various levels as needed.

```
def main():
    for value in possibilities('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'):
        print(value)


def possibilities(*args):
    if len(args) < 2:
        raise ValueError('at least two arguments must be given')
    if any(not isinstance(arg, str) for arg in args):
        raise TypeError('all arguments must be strings')
    if any(not arg for arg in args):
        raise ValueError('strings must have at least one character')
    matrix = [[''] + list(arg) for arg in args]

    def recursive_function(array):
        for index in range(len(array)):
            row = array.pop(index)
            if array:
                for column in row:
                    for next_item in recursive_function(array):
                        yield column + next_item
            else:
                yield from row
            array.insert(index, row)

    def unique(iterator):
        values = {''}
        for value in iterator:
            if value not in values:
                values.add(value)
                yield value
    return sorted(unique(recursive_function(matrix)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```